# Finding $H(x,y) = c$ satisfied by trajectories

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here's a problem from Boyce and Deprima (Ch. 9.2) I'm having trouble working through.

Find an equation of the form $H(x,y)=c$ satisfied by the trajectories, where $\frac{dx}{dt} = y$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2x + y$.

There's two ways I can see this being solved.  One is to find the solution, which is 
$$
x = c_{1}e^{2t} + c_2 e^{-t}\\
y = c_{1}2e^{2t} - c_2 e^{-t}\\
$$
and then take wild guesses at some function H such that H(x,y) = 0.  The second is to use a method where we suppose that y can be defined in terms of x implicitly and take $\frac{dy}{dt}/ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x+y}{y}$.  However, I can't find an H such that $H_x = 2x + y$ and $H_y = y$.

Answer (score 0):

Re-write dy/dx as (2*x+y)dx-ydy = 0. This equation is homogeneous and can be solved by letting y = x*v(x).  (This is covered in section 2.2 in your B & Dp text). Working through and and changing back to the original variables, you will arrive at
H(x,y) = (x+y)(y-2*x)^2. The origin is a saddle point. Then the lines you want are 
y = -x and y = 2*x. You can draw the trajectories; pay attention to their slopes as they go from quadrant to quadrant. 
Greg L.